# FIR FIlter Design on FPGA

Tags: matlab, fpga

I am designing a 9-Tap FIR filter, I have used MATLAB to get the filter coefficients

```
 -0.0041    0.0077    0.0893    0.2433    0.3276    0.2433    0.0893    0.0077   -0.0041
```

I have multiplied all the coefficients with a scaling factor to scale them to 16bits. The input to the filter are random 200 values generated by a custom MATLAB code

The maximum value of the sample data is 6.3445 and the minimum value is -7.5099. I am trying to figure out if I should scale the coefficients and the input data using the same scaling factor or should I use separate scaling factor for each. If I should scale both using the same scaling factor then how can I calculate that factor?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will use integer arithmetic, hence the scaling. How much you scale the input depends on the accuracy/performance of the filter you need. Basically what I do is:

```
input_integer_value = trunc(input_value*scale_factor_input);
coeff_integer_value = trunc(coeff_value*scale_coeff);
```

Since you got the function in Matlab, you can run the filter with the new input/coefficient values and compare them to the floating point

```
input_integer_converted = input_integer_value/scale_factor_input;
coeff_integer_converted = coeff_integer_value/scale_coeff;
```

Now you can vary the scale factors and see which gives you the best performance w.r.t. number of bits.

Hope it helps.